# onClick React no funciona

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Estoy haciendo una app con react que consiste en aumentar el valor de una variable cont al pulsar un boton; sin embargo, cuando presiono el boton no aumentan el valor de la variable llamada cont.

No me aparece ningun error al compilar  y en el navegador no sale errores, saben que podria estar pasando?

```
import React from 'react';

class EsPrimo extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            cont:1,
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={()=>this.setState.cont=this.setState.cont+1}>add</button>
                <div>{this.state.cont}</div>
            </div>
        );
    };
}

export default EsPrimo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Es porque estás haciendo el update the forma incorrecta. Set state no es un `setter`, es un método.

Para poder hacer el uso correcto del mismo debes usar: `this.setState({})` donde el argumento a pasar, que es un diccionario, tiene todos los atributos que quieres actualizar del estado.

Por lo tanto, para actualizar tu estado de forma correcta debes hacer:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.setState({cont: this.state.cont + 1})}>add</button>
```

Aquí esta un demo de como funciona: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-sinoussi-xm4hf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Acabo de hacer los cambios que recomiendas y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Realmente no puedo saber que cambio hiciste si no actualizas tu pregunta. Si copiaste y pegaste mi código sin darte cuenta que tenía un error entonces no va a funcionar. Escribí `count` en lugar de `cont`. De cualquier forma en la respuesta corregí el error y añadí un demo que muestra como funciona.

Comment: Ya pude solucionar mi problema, tuve que reinstalar el node js